Get a vector that starts at a given point and is a tangent to some given object
Currently the code recives a rectangle and determines the Vector2 positions of its corners. It will then calculate the new positions of the corners with the Sin and Cos relative to the angle of the rectangle. Currently it works only with rectangles.
The question I have is how can the code be updated to that it works with any type of shape/object. I don't need a code, just explaining the algorithm is fine.
foreach (var hit in hit_objects)
{
    Collider2D hitCollider = hit.collider;
    Bounds bounds = hitCollider.bounds;

    Vector2[] corners = new Vector2[4];
    corners[0] = new Vector2(bounds.min.x, bounds.min.y); 
    corners[1] = new Vector2(bounds.max.x, bounds.min.y); 
    corners[2] = new Vector2(bounds.max.x, bounds.max.y); 
    corners[3] = new Vector2(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.y);

    Vector2 center = bounds.center;
    float angle = hit.collider.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    for (int i = 0; i < corners.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector2 direction = corners[i] - center;
        float rotatedX = direction.x * Mathf.Cos(angle) - direction.y * Mathf.Sin(angle);
        float rotatedY = direction.x * Mathf.Sin(angle) + direction.y * Mathf.Cos(angle);
        corners[i] = new Vector2(rotatedX, rotatedY) + center;

        Debug.Log(corners[i] + "   " + i);

        Vector2 directionToCorner = (corners[i] - (Vector2)transform.position);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, directionToCorner, Color.green);
    }
}


well, if you know the angle of the sides that meet at the point, you should be able to calculate the tangent.  So you would need to know trhe lnes/planes that form the edges, and being old its been a long time since i was at school but it should be possible to get the angle, therefore half the angle, and then have it pass through to the outside, and it would be the tangent of the corner, as long as I understood the question

I don't know about that, I just realized that I can just aproximate it, using bisection or something.

@BugFinder at least for a circle it would be somewhat "trivial" .. if we are talking about more complex shapes it could get tricky

Not really because if you can find the corners, you can get the vectors and follow mathematics to get the angle, and therefore the tangent https://youtu.be/TTom8n3FFCw

@BugFinder well you would have to check each and every vertex/edge of a mesh and then see whether the vertex is "visible" to the point and which one would be the best fit for the tangent .. even with a circle the remaining issue still is that there are always two tangents .. OP needs to decide which one to take .. we don't need math to get the angle between two vectors ;) just use Vector2.SignedAngle

Overview
The goal is to find tangent lines from a starting object (let’s call it “A”) to an obstacle (target object “B”) in a Unity 2D environment. This is achieved by progressively narrowing down the tangent direction using a bisection method. This approach helps approximate tangent lines by testing and adjusting directions until they align with the edge of the target object.
The code description
In each frame, the script detects if something is in the way.
get_tangents is called to initiate the tangent calculations for each obstacle detected.
It calculates a perpendicular vector to the line connecting “A” and the “B”'s closest point. This perpendicular vector helps define a starting point for the tangent direction approximation.
The function then performs a bisection, aiming to get closer to the tangent lines with each iteration.
There are two main points, the position 1 (inside the object “B”), and the position 2 (outside the object “B”). This function uses midpoint of these two positions to test if vector going through “A” to this midpoint intersects the target object, if it does this midpoint becomes the position 1 otherwise it becomes the position 2.
After some iterations, the found tangent is quite accurate.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Burst.CompilerServices;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class tangents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask obstacleLayerMaskPF;
    public int max_number_of_iterations = 100;

    private Transform Player;
    private List<RaycastHit2D> hit_objects = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 rayStart = transform.position;
        Vector2 player_direction = (Player.position - transform.position);
        Debug.DrawRay(rayStart, player_direction, Color.red);

        // Perform a raycast and get all the hits
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(rayStart, player_direction, player_direction.magnitude, obstacleLayerMaskPF);

        hit_objects.Clear();
        hit_objects.AddRange(hits);

        get_tangents(hit_objects, this.transform.position, 0, player_direction);
    }

    void get_tangents(List<RaycastHit2D> hit_objects, Vector2 starting_position, int iteration, Vector2 player_direction)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        Vector2 center;
        Vector2 perpendicular_vector;
        Vector2[] start_middle_end = new Vector2[3];
        Vector2 closest_point_to_target;
        Vector2 vector_to_target;
        Vector2 perpendicular_vector_to_target;
        foreach (var hit in hit_objects)
        {
            closest_point_to_target = hit.collider.ClosestPoint(transform.position);
            vector_to_target = closest_point_to_target - (Vector2)transform.position;
            perpendicular_vector_to_target = new Vector2(vector_to_target.y, -vector_to_target.x);

            if (i == iteration)
            {
                center = hit.collider.transform.position;
                for (k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {

                    perpendicular_vector = new Vector2(player_direction.y, -player_direction.x) * (k - 1 + (k * 2));
                    start_middle_end[0] = center;
                    start_middle_end[2] = (Vector2)transform.position + perpendicular_vector_to_target.normalized * hit.collider.bounds.extents.magnitude * 2 * (k - 1 + (k * 2));
                    
                    for (j = 0; j < max_number_of_iterations; j++) 
                    {
                        bisection(hit.collider.gameObject, perpendicular_vector, center, start_middle_end);
                    }
                    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, (start_middle_end[2] - (Vector2)transform.position) * 5, Color.red);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    void bisection(GameObject obstacle, Vector2 perpendicular_vector, Vector2 center, Vector2[] start_middle_end)
    {
        bool hit_the_obstacle = false;
        start_middle_end[1] = (start_middle_end[0] + start_middle_end[2]) / 2;
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, start_middle_end[1] - (Vector2)transform.position, (start_middle_end[1] - (Vector2)transform.position).magnitude * 2, obstacleLayerMaskPF);
        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject == obstacle)
                {
                    hit_the_obstacle = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hit_the_obstacle) 
        {
            start_middle_end[0] = start_middle_end[1];
        }
        else start_middle_end[2] = start_middle_end[1];
    }

}


instead of a raycast sounds like using a Linecast would be better as you already know your start and end points
